# How can you programatically scroll a WrapGrid to a specific item within its ItemSource in a Windows Store App?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I have the following:

```
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapGrid Orientation="Vertical"
                  MaximumRowsOrColumns="10" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

I would like to scroll to a specific item, but can't find out how.

So far I have:

```
int itemIndex = ...;
var scrollBar = TheGridView.GetFirstDescendantOfType<ScrollViewer>();
scrollBar.ScrollToHorizontalOffset((double)itemIndex / NumberRows);
```

... but that feels oddly hacky, and means that I have to programatically calculate the number of rows.

```
const int IndividualItemHeight = /* Nasty Hard-Coded thing */;
numberOfRows = (int)((TheGridView.ActualHeight - TheGridView.Padding.Top -
                      TheGridView.Padding.Bottom) / IndividualItemHeight);
```

... which is even more hacky.

There must be a better way. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To scroll into specific view with GridView you just need to get access to the object which you bind to the Grid View item and invoke [ListViewBase.ScrollIntoView(Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br242911.aspx)

Comment: I was looking for a function on WrapGrid. ScrollIntoView is indeed on GridView.